# How to dynamically render image by sending image URL from ruby on rails application to BIRT report generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, birt

I am trying to dynamically load an image in the BIRT report by sending the image url through CSV file(data source) from the ruby on rails application.

The URL is an amazon AWS s3 url and image is in jpeg format. The error in the BIRT report shows "Resource of this item is not reachable".

However, a statically embedded url of an image works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! First I was sending a 'https' URI. It must not be.

Second, In the image source in dataset advanced settings the URI and On Render value must be assigned with the path !

[image: As shown here]